# What is the purpose of the thread entry point method/function?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, posix

when creating a thread we pass an entry point method/function , why should I have this method , what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @KenWhite That seems a bit harsh.  This question comes across to me more as "how do threads work" from someone who doesn't speak English natively. And an inexperienced programmer with perfect knowledge of English has a tough enough time to even know where to start looking to find answers - they don't even know the correct words to use for the questions that they do ask.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It was meant to be somewhat tongue in cheek. But you're right; when I re-read it from the viewpoint you describe, it did come across a little harsh. I've deleted it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS needs to know where a new thread of execution starts. When using a high-level programming language, one does not specify an address of machine instructions in memory to be executed in the context of a new thread, but uses execution units defined in the language like functions or methods. If thread creation worked like `fork` and execution of a new thread started at the point of `fork` invocation, then both threads would have the same local variables that usually reside in stack. Even if there is a copy of the stack created for a new thread, both threads will run the same clean-up code when leaving scopes (e.g., in C++ a smart pointer will be freed twice). So when you specify a starting point for a new thread, you are sure it will allocate a stack-frame of its own and function's epilog won't be executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

A thread has to start somewhere.  The pthread interface requires you to provide a function of the form

```
void *start_thread( void *arg );
```

`void *` is used because they can refer to anything.

When a thread is created, the function to provide is called as the thread's starting point.  Think of it like `main()` for the thread, but with different argument and return types.